# How to install proprietary driver

Tags: installation, 10.04, drivers, proprietary

Where do proprietary drivers go in **10.04 LTS**? It says there are no proprietary drivers available.

The driver I want to install came in a folder named `hybrid-portsrc_x86_32` followed by `-v5_100_82_112`.  (The contents of this folder are folders named lib and src and a file named Makefile.)  Where should it go in my Ubuntu folders, so it shows up on the Hardware Drivers list?

Answer (score 1):

According to [what I believe is the readme for this driver](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt), it should already be available in Ubuntu's repos. If it does not appear in the third-party drivers menu, the readme says to run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And then reboot. Have you tried this?

Comment: No, I have not tried this, but I will, and thank you. (It sounds like you are saying I should already have the driver in my system, and that the sudo command you provide should make it visible or "activate" it or whatever, which would be great.)

Comment: That didn't work.  Thank you for the link to the ReadMe, I am going to try exploring its guidance further.